# How to install other Maven packages in one pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

I have this file structure in my project:

```
Project  
|--pom.xml  
|--Sub-Module1
|----pom.xml
|--Sub-Module2
|----pom.xml
|--Sub-Module3
|----pom.xml
```

I want to create a JAR-file from Sub-Module2 (SM from now on). However, that module depends on SM1 and SM3. What I want to do is simply run "mvn package" from SM2 and it would run "mvn install" for SM1 and SM3. I already have SM1 and SM3 added to SM2's pom.xml as dependencies, so they get packaged in the JAR-file, but each time I start from fresh, I have to separately run "mvn install" in SM1 and SM3.

Is there a plugin for that or can I install other modules from SM2 in other means?

Comment: are your sub-modules other projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke `mvn package` on project level insteed of module level. This way Maven will build all three modules, and include required dependencies in generated jar as expected.

I assume that `pom.xml` in Project directory, is a parent pom for submodules.

EDIT: After quick check on Maven docs, you could use `mvn --also-make` and this should build dependant modules as well.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option. The actual project is much larger than that. The file structure is a simplified example of the actual file structure.

Comment: I would write simple script that would build 3 modules for me in correct order. I did something like that when I had similar problem.

Comment: You could give a shot some for some command options https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html eg. `--also-make` could do the trick here

Comment: Ah, that sounds exactly what I need. Thanks